# How to take column from matrix, and keep it 2D?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like to take `i`-th column from matrix `x`

[image]

I can do this by

```
x[:, i][:, np.newaxis]
```

is it the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Not sure about the best way</s>  Here's few -

```
x[:,[i]]
x[:, i, np.newaxis] # or use None in place of np.newaxis
np.atleast_2d(x[:,i]).T
x[:,i].reshape(-1,1)
```

Now, the first one is a copy and hence won't be the best way I would think, at least thinking in terms of memory efficiency, which might affect  performance efficiency as well. Others are just views into the input array and as such should be better. Let's verify that -

```
In [178]: x = np.random.rand(3,4)

In [180]: np.shares_memory(x, x[:,[2]] )
Out[180]: False

In [181]: np.shares_memory(x, x[:, 2, np.newaxis] )
Out[181]: True

In [182]: np.shares_memory(x, np.atleast_2d(x[:,2]).T )
Out[182]: True

In [199]: np.shares_memory(x,x[:,2].reshape(-1,1))
Out[199]: True
```

Let's test it out on the field as well. Let's do some addition of that slice with another array -

```
In [200]: x = np.random.rand(10000000,10)

In [201]: i = 5

In [202]: a = np.random.rand(x.shape[0],1)

In [203]: %timeit a + x[:,[i]]
     ...: %timeit a + x[:, i, np.newaxis]
     ...: %timeit a + np.atleast_2d(x[:,i]).T
     ...: %timeit a + x[:,i].reshape(-1,1)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 97.6 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 68.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 68.5 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 68.5 ms per loop
```

Hence, verifying the idea discussed earlier.

Comment: @@Divikar, thanks for adding your explanation about memory efficiency.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Sure! Also, added one more angle to the performance numbers by testing out with addition, just verifies the concept of views.

Comment: `x[:,2:3]` is another option that creates a view.

Comment: @hpaulj Yup! Thanks for adding that in.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply solve your problem by:

`x[:, [i]]`

As @Divakar has mentioned, you can also achieve the same result using `x[:, i, np.newaxis]` and `np.atleast_2d(x[:,i]).T`. However, the fastest seems to be x[:, i, np.newaxis]:

```
In [1]: %timeit x[:, [1]]
11.6 µs ± 87.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit x[:, 1, np.newaxis] # fastest
3.05 µs ± 108 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [16]: %timeit np.atleast_2d(x[:,1]).T
14.2 µs ± 113 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for timing! I was thinking about adding those :) That view/copy thing is probably affecting the timings.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a slice of length 1:

```
In [2]: x
Out[2]: 
array([[8, 7, 4, 5, 5],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 6],
       [0, 7, 2, 5, 0],
       [0, 1, 6, 8, 5]])

In [3]: i = 3  # Which column to select.

In [4]: x[:, i:i+1]  # Use the slice i:i+1 to select the column.
Out[4]: 
array([[5],
       [3],
       [5],
       [8]])
```

This is a bit slower than `x[:, i, np.newaxis]`, possibly because of the expression `i+1` that has to be evaluated.

Comment: Seems comparable to me (timings). Good addition.